IllegalArgumentException with spigot minecraft plugin
I have an error:
Could not pass event AsyncPlayerChatEvent to SupremeChat v1.3.2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.bukkit.Sound.ENTITY_LEVELUP
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.Sound.valueOf(Sound.java:13) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.devscape.project.supremechat.listeners.Mention.onMention(Mention.java:64) ~[SupremeChat-1.3.2.jar:?]
    at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor700.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$2.execute(EventExecutor.java:77) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:77) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:git-Paper-497]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperEventManager.callEvent(PaperEventManager.java:54) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-497]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.callEvent(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:126) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-497]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:615) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.adventure.ChatProcessor.post(ChatProcessor.java:378) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-497]
    at io.papermc.paper.adventure.ChatProcessor.process(ChatProcessor.java:85) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-497]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.chat(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2318) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.broadcastChatMessage(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2447) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.lambda$handleChat$13(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2167) ~[?:?]

I don't know the solution

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, the information you included in the question is probably insufficient for us to be able to use to solve your problem. To better understand how to use this site, I suggest browsing using these resources and their linked pages: The Tour, How to write a good question, and other pages in the Help Center.

Question titles should be about a specific issue. Here are some more pages that might help you better use Stack Overflow:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-a-useful-question  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Can you include the relevant code that is associated with this error?

The code you are using mention old Sound enum variables.
Instead of using ENTITY_LEVELUP, you should use ENTITY_PLAYER_LEVELUP.
Spigot renamed all of this since Spigot 1.13 to make it as Minecraft's names.
Also, the plugin you are using is no in latest version. You can find latest here

if you can tell me exactly what should i do i will appreciate it i dont know anything about it

@cmstormhox try to update to latest to the given link, it should works fine for your version

i downloaded the latest version but still not working

@cmstormhox Can you [edit] your post to define what's "not working"? and show the new error
